# MYSQL duplication caused by inner join

Tags: mysql

The issue i face is that i have just added a further to columns to a mysql table 
The query now produces a duplicate record set, having read lots of examples on this issue i am having trouble relating it to my on issue and therefore have not been able to correct the problem 
I am using netbeans 7.4 and java 7 and mysql server 5.1
Here is the query

```
                String query = "SELECT * FROM books "
           + "INNER JOIN author ON author.author_id = books. Author "
           + "INNER JOIN title  ON title.title_id = books.title "
           + "INNER JOIN publisher  ON publisher.publisher_id = books.publisher "
           + "INNER JOIN format  ON format.format_id = books.format "
           + "INNER JOIN newgenre  ON newgenre.value = books.newgenre "
           + "INNER JOIN language  ON language.language_id = books.Language "
           + "INNER JOIN post ON post. postage_id= books.postagetype "
           + "INNER JOIN usedcondition  ON usedcondition.general_id=books.general_id"
           + "INNER JOIN fettle  ON fettle.fettle_id= books.fettle "
           + "WHERE isbn13 =" + theData;
```

The last two joins are for some reason unknown to me creating a duplicate record set, if i remove them everything work find but for the missing data 
The format table and the usedcondition are the same apart from the names of columns each have just a title column of type int and an information column of type varchar
The reason i mention this i constructed this query one stage at a time and format was added long ago without and side effects and the application ran fine
So if you can help me understand what i am doing wrong then just maybe i can correct the issue

Comment: What happens if you change them to left joins, or unspecified joins? Can you provide sample results so we can actually see what's happening?

Comment: The whole point of `a INNER JOIN b` is to create a combinatorial explosion: to retrieve duplicate records if more than one row in `a` matches a row in `b` or vice versa.